# Question about methods of u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

This is essentially a question about an answer I received at -
[Integrating a function using u-substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777325/integrating-a-function-using-u-substitution). Initially, I thought I understood it, but looking at it, I do have uncertainties.

I just want to understand if I got the right idea solving, so I will be listing the steps and my uncertainties alongside with them:

Quoting steps from amWhy:

> $$\int\ \frac {e^{2x}-6e^x}{e^x+2}\ dx$$
>
> Let $\displaystyle e^x + 2 = u$.$^{\color{blue}{(1)}}$
>
> So $\displaystyle e^x = u-2$, and so $\displaystyle e^{2x} = (u-2)^2$.
>
> $\color{blue}{(1)}$ Now $\displaystyle e^x \ dx = du \iff \ dx = \frac{du}{e^x}$, but recall from above, that $\displaystyle e^x = u-2$.
>
> So in fact, $\displaystyle \color{blue}{dx = \frac{du}{u-2}}$.
>
> That gives us the integral
>
> $$\begin{align} \int \frac{(u-2)^2 - 6(u-2)}{u\cdot \color{blue}{(u-2)}}\ >\color{blue}{du} & = \int \frac{(u-2) - 6}{u}\,du \\ & = \int \frac{u-8}{u}\,du >\\ &= \int \left(1- \frac 8u\right)\ du = \end{align}$$

I understand the part where we take $dx=\frac{du}{e^x}$ turn it into $dx=\frac{du}{u-2}$, what I don't understand is why we ACTUALLY MULTIPLY the whole equation of $\int \frac{(u-2)^2 - 6(u-2)}{(u)}$ by $\frac{du}{u-2}$.

I will give you an example of why it doesn't make sense to me:

Say we have:

> $\int \frac{(5x^4)}{x^5+5}dx$ >> $u=x^5+5$ and THIS: $du=5x^4 dx$ or just $\frac {du}{5x^4}=dx$ >> $\int \frac{1}{u}du$

Now we don't actually multiply the whole equation by $\frac {du}{5x^4}$, it just turns into $du$, so why did we do it in the first example?

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Comment: Sorry in advance for any headache caused ^^

Comment: Do you know why the $5x^4$ in the numerator disappears after the substitution? It is cancelled by the $\frac{du}{5x^4}$!

Comment: Holy **** I knew I missed something stupid. Thanks so much Szeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose we wished to integrate 
$$\int{\frac{5x^4}{x^5+5}dx}$$

You suppose we take $u=x^5+5$, then $\frac{du}{dx}=5x^4\to du=5x^4 dx$

In this particular case, it makes sense to leave the $5x^4$ as-is, as it is involved in the integral anyway
So
$$\int{\frac{{5x^4}}{x^5+5}dx}$$
becomes $$\int{\frac 1u du}=\ln|u|+C$$
Because $du=5x^4dx$ and $u=x^5+5$

You may have noticed that $5x^4$ is the derivative of $x^5+5$, as a shortcut you can say:
$$\int{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx}=\ln|f(x)|+C$$

Let me now show you another integral where $u$-substitution is used:

Suppose we want: $$\int{\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}$$

Let $x=\tan(u)$, then $\frac{dx}{du}=\sec^2(u)\to dx=\sec^2(u)du$

Now since we have $dx$ in terms of $du$, we can replace it so:
$$\int{\frac{1}{x^2+1}\sec^2(u)du}$$
And we can replace the $x$ with $\tan(u)$, so:
$$\int{\frac{1}{\tan^2(u)+1}\sec^2(u)du}$$
And since $\tan^2(u)+1=\sec^2(u)$, we get $$\int{\frac{sec^2(u)}{sec^2(u)}du}=\int{1 du}=u+C$$

In the first example you gave, this process is the same, you simply replace $dx$ by the equivalent $\frac{1}{u-2}du$